# how cancel log4js input color flag to logfiles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, record, log4js-node

> My Log4js configure  | based node.js

```
    layout: {
             type: 'pattern',
             pattern: '%d - %m%n' 
    }
```

> I user this method to record log

```
 var duration = new Date() - t;
 logger.info('Started', req.method, req.url, req.ip);
 logger.info('Completed', req.url, res.statusCode,  ('(' + duration + 'ms)').green);
```

> Output to a log file

2016-07-13 14:24:37.188 - Started POST /findBalance ::ffff:127.0.0.1

2016-07-13 14:24:37.189 - Started POST /planadreport ::ffff:127.0.0.1

2016-07-13 14:24:37.278 - Completed /findBalance 200 [32m(90ms)[39m

2016-07-13 14:24:37.292 - Completed /planadreport 200 [32m(103ms)[39m

2016-07-13 14:26:38.028 - Started GET /advert ::ffff:127.0.0.1

2016-07-13 14:26:38.112 - [32mStarted GET / ::ffff:127.0.0.1[39m

2016-07-13 14:26:38.135 - [32mCompleted /advert 302 [32m(111ms)[39m[39m

2016-07-13 14:26:38.206 - [32mCompleted / 304 [32m(94ms)[39m[39m

2016-07-13 14:26:40.454 - [32mStarted GET /login ::ffff:127.0.0.1[39m

2016-07-13 14:26:40.549 - [32mCompleted /login 304 [32m(95ms)[39m[39m

> Problems encountered

**[32m and [39m**  =>it's the color start and end flag I do not record them to datafile..  However, any word I want to print color on the console

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc of log4js, the color will effect via defining "%[ and %]" bloc.
Get more details to ref https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/wiki/Layouts

Comment: May be this has answered your question. https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/issues/304